# how to give size dynamically in each marker in jfree scatter chart

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to give different size on each marker in jfree chart but it is not working below code size applied for all the markers

redRenderer.setSeriesShape(Numbers.ZERO, new Ellipse2D.Double(-4, -4, 8, 8));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.